# How to find all possible paths in 2d array of numbers from the first to the last, where each step's value is greater than the previous step?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, maze

The code I've got so far finds only 2 possible paths.  How can I rework it to find all of them?

An example of a valid path would be, begin with the first array `[1, 32]`.  Choose a number to step from, like `32`.

Look at the next array immediately below: `[11, 21, 24, 27, 35, 37, 65]`.  A valid step would be to any of these numbers that are greater than your current step.  So `35`, `37`, and `65` would all be valid steps.

And continue constructing the path by taking steps onto the other arrays in order (top to bottom) until you reach the last.

```js
'use strict';

const matrix = [
  [1, 32],
  [11, 21, 24, 27, 35, 37, 65],
  [17, 22, 25, 51, 57, 63],
  [18, 56]
];

function findPaths(arrays) {
  const paths = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arrays[0].length; i++) {
    const path = [arrays[0][i]];
    for (let j = 1; j < arrays.length; j++) {
      for (let y = 0; y < arrays[j].length; y++) {
        if (path[Math.max(0, path.length - 1)] < arrays[j][y]) {
          path.push(arrays[j][y]);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    paths.push(path);
  }
  return paths;
}

const result = findPaths(matrix);

console.log(result); // [ [ 1, 11, 17, 18 ], [ 32, 35, 51, 56 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.  It's not the most efficient solution, but I'm working on it.

```js
const data = [
  [1, 32],
  [11, 21, 24, 27, 35, 37, 65],
  [17, 22, 25, 51, 57, 63],
  [18, 56]
];

function findPaths(arrays) {
  const paths = [];
  const maxPaths = arrays.reduce((total, arr) => total *= arr.length || total, 1);
  for (let x = 0; x < maxPaths; x++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrays[0].length; i++) {
      const path = [arrays[0][i]];
      for (let j = 1; j < arrays.length; j++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < arrays[j].length; y++) {
          if (path[Math.max(0, path.length - 1)] < arrays[j][y]) {
            if (!paths.some(p => p.toString() == [...path, arrays[j][y]].toString())) {
              path.push(arrays[j][y]);
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      paths.push(path);
    }
  }
  return paths.filter(path => path.length == arrays.length).sort();
}

const result = findPaths(data);

console.log(result);

/*
[
  [ 1, 11, 17, 18 ],  [ 1, 11, 17, 56 ],
  [ 1, 11, 22, 56 ],  [ 1, 11, 25, 56 ],
  [ 1, 11, 51, 56 ],  [ 1, 21, 22, 56 ],
  [ 1, 21, 25, 56 ],  [ 1, 21, 51, 56 ],
  [ 1, 24, 25, 56 ],  [ 1, 24, 51, 56 ],
  [ 1, 27, 51, 56 ],  [ 1, 35, 51, 56 ],
  [ 1, 37, 51, 56 ],  [ 32, 35, 51, 56 ],
  [ 32, 37, 51, 56 ]
]
*/
```